# Can't log in to Google through Lightread

Tags: rss, lightread

I need some help from you...

after googling for 2 days, I'm unable to login into my google reader acount using lightread, I don't have google two factor authentification active so I don't have any idea of what it could be...

your help will be much apreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, press the cog (settings) button on the upper-right corner and sign out. Login again with your account and it should work. It worked for me.

Also, if the refreshing icon will keep spinning but wont update anything, try to change or make the refresh interval to manual. Just found out that.

Comment: I already tried this solution, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You should generate application specific password from your Google Account page (follow menu Security -> Apps passwords). Then put this newly generated password (looks like 'qwrt ruty uyre ofig" into the password fiels and you'll be logged in no time.